# Authorization error: migrating db for Google cloud SQL

Tags: sqlalchemy, authorization

I've been trying to make a db using google cloud sql, but I got an error when migrating the db.

`python manager.py db init` works well: A folder named `migrations` was made.

However, `python manager.py db migrate` produces an error:

```
   File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 946, in MakeRequest
raise _ToDbApiException(response.sql_exception)
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (InternalError) (0, u'End user Google Account not authorized.') None None
```

It looks like a kind of authorization errors. How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Former authentication information was saved in a file, '.googlesql_oauth2.dat', if you had been authorized with a different id.

In this case, you have to remove the file before authentication process is performed.

Mac:

```
~/.googlesql_oauth2.dat
```

Windows:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.googlesql_oauth2.dat
```

Ref: http://jhlim.kaist.ac.kr/?p=182